# pip: problem with the installation of mpi4py

Tags: python, pip

I am trying to install mpi4py in default python environment used by anaconda:

```
python3.9 -m pip install mpi4py
```

which produces error during installation

```
python -m pip install mpi4py
Collecting mpi4py
  Using cached mpi4py-3.1.3.tar.gz (2.5 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
    Preparing wheel metadata ... done
Building wheels for collected packages: mpi4py
  Building wheel for mpi4py (PEP 517) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: /home/gleb/anaconda3/bin/python /home/gleb/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py build_wheel /tmp/tmp75wsbtz5
       cwd: /tmp/pip-install-84g0ez5h/mpi4py_2ac6e87b98de43d3827e1b2951c5c4ff
  Complete output (156 lines):
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_src
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/mpi4py
  copying src/mpi4py/bench.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/mpi4py
  copying src/mpi4py/__main__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/mpi4py
  copying src/mpi4py/run.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/mpi4py
  copying src/mpi4py/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/mpi4py
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/mpi4py/futures
  copying src/mpi4py/futures/server.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/mpi4py/futures
  copying src/mpi4py/futures/pool.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/mpi4py/futures
  copying src/mpi4py/futures/_lib.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/mpi4py/futures
  copying src/mpi4py/futures/_base.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/mpi4py/futures
  copying src/mpi4py/futures/aplus.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/mpi4py/futures
  copying src/mpi4py/futures/__main__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/mpi4py/futures
  copying src/mpi4py/futures/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/mpi4py/futures
  copying src/mpi4py/futures/_core.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/mpi4py/futures
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/mpi4py/util
  copying src/mpi4py/util/dtlib.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/mpi4py/util
  copying src/mpi4py/util/pkl5.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/mpi4py/util
  copying src/mpi4py/util/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/mpi4py/util
  copying src/mpi4py/py.typed -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/mpi4py
  copying src/mpi4py/__main__.pyi -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/mpi4py
  copying src/mpi4py/dl.pyi -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/mpi4py
  copying src/mpi4py/MPI.pyi -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/mpi4py
  copying src/mpi4py/__init__.pyi -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/mpi4py
  copying src/mpi4py/bench.pyi -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/mpi4py
  copying src/mpi4py/run.pyi -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/mpi4py
  copying src/mpi4py/MPI.pxd -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/mpi4py
  copying src/mpi4py/libmpi.pxd -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/mpi4py
  copying src/mpi4py/__init__.pxd -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/mpi4py
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/mpi4py/include
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/mpi4py/include/mpi4py
  copying src/mpi4py/include/mpi4py/mpi4py.MPI.h -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/mpi4py/include/mpi4py
  copying src/mpi4py/include/mpi4py/mpi4py.h -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/mpi4py/include/mpi4py
  copying src/mpi4py/include/mpi4py/mpi4py.MPI_api.h -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/mpi4py/include/mpi4py
  copying src/mpi4py/include/mpi4py/mpi4py.i -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/mpi4py/include/mpi4py
  copying src/mpi4py/include/mpi4py/mpi.pxi -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/mpi4py/include/mpi4py
  copying src/mpi4py/futures/_lib.pyi -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/mpi4py/futures
  copying src/mpi4py/futures/__main__.pyi -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/mpi4py/futures
  copying src/mpi4py/futures/aplus.pyi -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/mpi4py/futures
  copying src/mpi4py/futures/__init__.pyi -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/mpi4py/futures
  copying src/mpi4py/futures/pool.pyi -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/mpi4py/futures
  copying src/mpi4py/futures/server.pyi -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/mpi4py/futures
  copying src/mpi4py/futures/_core.pyi -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/mpi4py/futures
  copying src/mpi4py/util/dtlib.pyi -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/mpi4py/util
  copying src/mpi4py/util/pkl5.pyi -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/mpi4py/util
  copying src/mpi4py/util/__init__.pyi -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/mpi4py/util
  running build_clib
  MPI configuration: [mpi] from 'mpi.cfg'
  MPI C compiler:    /home/gleb/anaconda3/bin/mpicc
  MPI C++ compiler:  /home/gleb/anaconda3/bin/mpicxx
  MPI F compiler:    /home/gleb/anaconda3/bin/mpifort
  MPI F90 compiler:  /home/gleb/anaconda3/bin/mpif90
  MPI F77 compiler:  /home/gleb/anaconda3/bin/mpif77
  checking for library 'lmpe' ...
  /home/gleb/anaconda3/bin/mpicc -pthread -B /home/gleb/anaconda3/compiler_compat -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -O2 -Wall -fPIC -O2 -isystem /home/gleb/anaconda3/include -I/home/gleb/anaconda3/include -fPIC -O2 -isystem /home/gleb/anaconda3/include -fPIC -c _configtest.c -o _configtest.o
  /home/gleb/anaconda3/bin/mpicc: line 301: x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu-cc: command not found
  failure.
  removing: _configtest.c _configtest.o
  building 'mpe' dylib library
  creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-39
  creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/src
  creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/src/lib-pmpi
  /home/gleb/anaconda3/bin/mpicc -pthread -B /home/gleb/anaconda3/compiler_compat -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -O2 -Wall -fPIC -O2 -isystem /home/gleb/anaconda3/include -I/home/gleb/anaconda3/include -fPIC -O2 -isystem /home/gleb/anaconda3/include -fPIC -c src/lib-pmpi/mpe.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/src/lib-pmpi/mpe.o
  /home/gleb/anaconda3/bin/mpicc: line 301: x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu-cc: command not found
  warning: build_clib: command '/home/gleb/anaconda3/bin/mpicc' failed with exit code 127
  
  warning: build_clib: building optional library "mpe" failed
  
  checking for library 'vt-mpi' ...
  /home/gleb/anaconda3/bin/mpicc -pthread -B /home/gleb/anaconda3/compiler_compat -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -O2 -Wall -fPIC -O2 -isystem /home/gleb/anaconda3/include -I/home/gleb/anaconda3/include -fPIC -O2 -isystem /home/gleb/anaconda3/include -fPIC -c _configtest.c -o _configtest.o
  /home/gleb/anaconda3/bin/mpicc: line 301: x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu-cc: command not found
  failure.
  removing: _configtest.c _configtest.o
  checking for library 'vt.mpi' ...
  /home/gleb/anaconda3/bin/mpicc -pthread -B /home/gleb/anaconda3/compiler_compat -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -O2 -Wall -fPIC -O2 -isystem /home/gleb/anaconda3/include -I/home/gleb/anaconda3/include -fPIC -O2 -isystem /home/gleb/anaconda3/include -fPIC -c _configtest.c -o _configtest.o
  /home/gleb/anaconda3/bin/mpicc: line 301: x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu-cc: command not found
  failure.
  removing: _configtest.c _configtest.o
  building 'vt' dylib library
  /home/gleb/anaconda3/bin/mpicc -pthread -B /home/gleb/anaconda3/compiler_compat -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -O2 -Wall -fPIC -O2 -isystem /home/gleb/anaconda3/include -I/home/gleb/anaconda3/include -fPIC -O2 -isystem /home/gleb/anaconda3/include -fPIC -c src/lib-pmpi/vt.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/src/lib-pmpi/vt.o
  /home/gleb/anaconda3/bin/mpicc: line 301: x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu-cc: command not found
  warning: build_clib: command '/home/gleb/anaconda3/bin/mpicc' failed with exit code 127
  
  warning: build_clib: building optional library "vt" failed
  
  checking for library 'vt-mpi' ...
  /home/gleb/anaconda3/bin/mpicc -pthread -B /home/gleb/anaconda3/compiler_compat -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -O2 -Wall -fPIC -O2 -isystem /home/gleb/anaconda3/include -I/home/gleb/anaconda3/include -fPIC -O2 -isystem /home/gleb/anaconda3/include -fPIC -c _configtest.c -o _configtest.o
  /home/gleb/anaconda3/bin/mpicc: line 301: x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu-cc: command not found
  failure.
  removing: _configtest.c _configtest.o
  checking for library 'vt.mpi' ...
  /home/gleb/anaconda3/bin/mpicc -pthread -B /home/gleb/anaconda3/compiler_compat -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -O2 -Wall -fPIC -O2 -isystem /home/gleb/anaconda3/include -I/home/gleb/anaconda3/include -fPIC -O2 -isystem /home/gleb/anaconda3/include -fPIC -c _configtest.c -o _configtest.o
  /home/gleb/anaconda3/bin/mpicc: line 301: x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu-cc: command not found
  failure.
  removing: _configtest.c _configtest.o
  building 'vt-mpi' dylib library
  /home/gleb/anaconda3/bin/mpicc -pthread -B /home/gleb/anaconda3/compiler_compat -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -O2 -Wall -fPIC -O2 -isystem /home/gleb/anaconda3/include -I/home/gleb/anaconda3/include -fPIC -O2 -isystem /home/gleb/anaconda3/include -fPIC -c src/lib-pmpi/vt-mpi.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/src/lib-pmpi/vt-mpi.o
  /home/gleb/anaconda3/bin/mpicc: line 301: x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu-cc: command not found
  warning: build_clib: command '/home/gleb/anaconda3/bin/mpicc' failed with exit code 127
  
  warning: build_clib: building optional library "vt-mpi" failed
  
  checking for library 'vt-hyb' ...
  /home/gleb/anaconda3/bin/mpicc -pthread -B /home/gleb/anaconda3/compiler_compat -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -O2 -Wall -fPIC -O2 -isystem /home/gleb/anaconda3/include -I/home/gleb/anaconda3/include -fPIC -O2 -isystem /home/gleb/anaconda3/include -fPIC -c _configtest.c -o _configtest.o
  /home/gleb/anaconda3/bin/mpicc: line 301: x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu-cc: command not found
  failure.
  removing: _configtest.c _configtest.o
  checking for library 'vt.ompi' ...
  /home/gleb/anaconda3/bin/mpicc -pthread -B /home/gleb/anaconda3/compiler_compat -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -O2 -Wall -fPIC -O2 -isystem /home/gleb/anaconda3/include -I/home/gleb/anaconda3/include -fPIC -O2 -isystem /home/gleb/anaconda3/include -fPIC -c _configtest.c -o _configtest.o
  /home/gleb/anaconda3/bin/mpicc: line 301: x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu-cc: command not found
  failure.
  removing: _configtest.c _configtest.o
  building 'vt-hyb' dylib library
  /home/gleb/anaconda3/bin/mpicc -pthread -B /home/gleb/anaconda3/compiler_compat -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -O2 -Wall -fPIC -O2 -isystem /home/gleb/anaconda3/include -I/home/gleb/anaconda3/include -fPIC -O2 -isystem /home/gleb/anaconda3/include -fPIC -c src/lib-pmpi/vt-hyb.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/src/lib-pmpi/vt-hyb.o
  /home/gleb/anaconda3/bin/mpicc: line 301: x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu-cc: command not found
  warning: build_clib: command '/home/gleb/anaconda3/bin/mpicc' failed with exit code 127
  
  warning: build_clib: building optional library "vt-hyb" failed
  
  running build_ext
  MPI configuration: [mpi] from 'mpi.cfg'
  MPI C compiler:    /home/gleb/anaconda3/bin/mpicc
  MPI C++ compiler:  /home/gleb/anaconda3/bin/mpicxx
  MPI F compiler:    /home/gleb/anaconda3/bin/mpifort
  MPI F90 compiler:  /home/gleb/anaconda3/bin/mpif90
  MPI F77 compiler:  /home/gleb/anaconda3/bin/mpif77
  checking for dlopen() availability ...
  checking for header 'dlfcn.h' ...
  gcc -pthread -B /home/gleb/anaconda3/compiler_compat -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -O2 -Wall -fPIC -O2 -isystem /home/gleb/anaconda3/include -I/home/gleb/anaconda3/include -fPIC -O2 -isystem /home/gleb/anaconda3/include -fPIC -I/home/gleb/anaconda3/include/python3.9 -c _configtest.c -o _configtest.o
  success!
  removing: _configtest.c _configtest.o
  success!
  checking for library 'dl' ...
  gcc -pthread -B /home/gleb/anaconda3/compiler_compat -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -O2 -Wall -fPIC -O2 -isystem /home/gleb/anaconda3/include -I/home/gleb/anaconda3/include -fPIC -O2 -isystem /home/gleb/anaconda3/include -fPIC -I/home/gleb/anaconda3/include/python3.9 -c _configtest.c -o _configtest.o
  gcc -pthread -B /home/gleb/anaconda3/compiler_compat _configtest.o -Lbuild/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-39 -ldl -o _configtest
  success!
  removing: _configtest.c _configtest.o _configtest
  checking for function 'dlopen' ...
  gcc -pthread -B /home/gleb/anaconda3/compiler_compat -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -O2 -Wall -fPIC -O2 -isystem /home/gleb/anaconda3/include -I/home/gleb/anaconda3/include -fPIC -O2 -isystem /home/gleb/anaconda3/include -fPIC -I/home/gleb/anaconda3/include/python3.9 -c _configtest.c -o _configtest.o
  gcc -pthread -B /home/gleb/anaconda3/compiler_compat _configtest.o -Lbuild/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-39 -ldl -o _configtest
  success!
  removing: _configtest.c _configtest.o _configtest
  building 'mpi4py.dl' extension
  gcc -pthread -B /home/gleb/anaconda3/compiler_compat -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -O2 -Wall -fPIC -O2 -isystem /home/gleb/anaconda3/include -I/home/gleb/anaconda3/include -fPIC -O2 -isystem /home/gleb/anaconda3/include -fPIC -DHAVE_DLFCN_H=1 -DHAVE_DLOPEN=1 -I/home/gleb/anaconda3/include/python3.9 -c src/dynload.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/src/dynload.o
  gcc -pthread -B /home/gleb/anaconda3/compiler_compat -shared -Wl,-rpath,/home/gleb/anaconda3/lib -Wl,-rpath-link,/home/gleb/anaconda3/lib -L/home/gleb/anaconda3/lib -L/home/gleb/anaconda3/lib -Wl,-rpath,/home/gleb/anaconda3/lib -Wl,-rpath-link,/home/gleb/anaconda3/lib -L/home/gleb/anaconda3/lib build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/src/dynload.o -Lbuild/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-39 -ldl -o build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/mpi4py/dl.cpython-39-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
  checking for MPI compile and link ...
  /home/gleb/anaconda3/bin/mpicc -pthread -B /home/gleb/anaconda3/compiler_compat -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -O2 -Wall -fPIC -O2 -isystem /home/gleb/anaconda3/include -I/home/gleb/anaconda3/include -fPIC -O2 -isystem /home/gleb/anaconda3/include -fPIC -I/home/gleb/anaconda3/include/python3.9 -c _configtest.c -o _configtest.o
  /home/gleb/anaconda3/bin/mpicc: line 301: x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu-cc: command not found
  failure.
  removing: _configtest.c _configtest.o
  error: Cannot compile MPI programs. Check your configuration!!!
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for mpi4py
Failed to build mpi4py
ERROR: Could not build wheels for mpi4py which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly
```

Then I tried

```
sudo pip install mpi4py
```

that installed the package correctly but into another python environment
so python does not see it

```
Python 3.9.12 (main, Apr  5 2022, 06:56:58) 
[GCC 7.5.0] :: Anaconda, Inc. on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

>>> import mpi4py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mpi4py'
```

Finally I've tried simply

```
sudo apt install python3-mpi4py
```

it installed package correclty but my python3 enviroment still does not see it.

I also tried

```
conda install -c conda-forge mpi4py
```

which does not work as well:

```
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: failed with repodata from current_repodata.json, will retry with next repodata source.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: - failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
```

how could I execute python3.9 -m pip install mpi4py with sudo ?

Comment: Don't use `sudo pip`, recipe to break stuff. Esspecially since you have anaconda installed there is no need for it

Comment: I would suggest to try `conda install -c conda-forge mpi4py`. Please inlcude the **full** output from `python -m pip install mpi4py` into your question

Comment: I've just updated my post

Comment: Did `conda install -c conda-forge mpi4py` work?

Comment: please see update of my post

Comment: Looks like it is failing to solve the dependencies (as anaconda base is **huge**). Do you depserately need it in the overloaded base env or is creating an env for your project an option?

Comment: No actually It's done! I could install it via conda so ..